# Is there a way to elevate CMD to admin, and run a Batch file in that same command prompt instance?

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that comes from a python program, that writes Registry Editing commands from user input and to execute these commands to have them work, ALL need admin rights. Currently I am using

`"powershell -Command Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs|c:\users\T\Desktop\output.bat"`

Which seems like it would work (To a noob like myself) and when I run this command, it opens a command prompt window as administrator, BUT the problem is that the "output.bat" file runs in the NON ADMIN Command prompt.

Comment: There would be no security if processes could raise their own privileges — think about it.

Comment: Did you consider reasding the help information for the Start-Process cmdlet, `Get-Help Start-Process -Full`? Had you done so, you may have noticed the `-ArgumentList` option. `"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "Start-Process '%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/C', '\"C:\Users\T\Desktop\output.bat\"' -Verb RunAs"`.